# Salesforce1 Tasks Navigation Menu Item

Tags: salesforce1-app, tasks

You can add a Tasks menu item to the navigation menu in Salesforce1. When clicking that menu item, you are brought to a page that lists your tasks. There is also a *Log a Call* button at the top along with a filter for filtering the tasks list.

Is there any way to add a *New Task* button to this page or customize it in any way such that you can create a new task? If not, is there any way to create a new standalone task, much like you can from the Home page in Salesforce Classic, in Salesforce1?